# Insert character before every word in textarea

Tags: jquery

Insert character before every word in textarea
using only jquery, Insert character "#" before every word typed in textarea. the problem is only # is inserted at first word.Rest I had done
demo at : http://jsfiddle.net/LKUbr/11/

```
  <textarea name='name' id='name'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Sign Up' id='signUp' onclick="count()"/> 

  function count(){  
 var words = $('textarea').val().split(' ');
    words='#'+words;
alert(words);//or return words.length;
}
```

Comment: What about words that already have a `#` symbol at the front? What if there are multiple spaces between words? etc etc.

Comment: Questions that can be reduced to "Please do my work for me" will generally be down voted and closed. We need to see what you've tried and the specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: Simple join `words = $('textarea').val().split(' ').join('#');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31982725/1479535

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jrx5Z/51/

Comment: I had already shown what i had tried and where is the problem @ Jamie Dixon

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what exactly you want but

```
    $("#event_content").keyup(function(e,v){
    var text = $(this).val();
    return $(this).val(text.replace(" ", "#"));
   });
```

It will return abc#sd#sd every space will be replace with #

http://jsfiddle.net/jrx5Z/49/

Comment: i need space between them. and i am getting them comma separated by using var words = $('textarea').val().split(' ');
alert(words); 
but it is not working because of using return

Comment: space between two hash words?

Comment: Ok, I get it but the first word does not get hash tag and also if i want to write some word starting with #, then another # comes up. like if i write #abc, it writes ##abc

Answer (score 1):

You can add space after you have done with the code. or else they will keep on multiplying. Regular expression can be used for solving this.

```js
$("#event_content").keyup(function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if(text.charAt(0) !== '#')
        text = '#' + text;
    text = text.replace(/( )+(#)*( )*/g, " #");
    return $(this).val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="event_content" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: the first word does not have # and when i delete #, it does not get deleted

Comment: but it doesnot let me write another word.

Comment: when i delete last #, it does not get deleted. rest is fine